# Dynamic Routing With Bottle.py

Tags: python, bottle

I'm very new to the Bottle framework and am having a hard time understanding what I am doing wrong when trying to serve static files using dynamic routes.

The following works just fine for me when I use exact values:

```
@route('/files/somefile.txt')
def serve_somefile():
   return static_file('somefile.txt', root = '/directory/to/files')
```

However, I am trying to create a dynamic route to serve any file in the /files directory based on the [documentation](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#dynamic-routes).

This does not work for me:

```
@route('/files/<filename>')
def serve_somefile(filename):
   return static_file(filename, root= '/directory/to/files')
```

I get a 404 response from the server, despite it receiving an identical GET request compared to the above example.

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Were there any other routes defined before that bottle had already matched. For example /<filename:path> would cause  /files/<filename> to 404

Answer (score 2):

Did you try specifying the parameter as path (like in their example):

```
@route('/files/<filename:path>')
def serve_somefile(filename):
    return static_file(filename, root= '/directory/to/files')
```

Comment: `filename:path` is so that it can serve files within subdirectories.

Comment: Unfortunately, adding the :path filter does not make a difference. Still get the 404.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in your code looks wrong to me.  (And I agree with @Ashalynd that you should be using `:path` here.)

In fact, I tried running your code, and *both* cases work.

Perhaps you're using an old version of Bottle?  I'm on 0.12.7.

--

Here's my complete example, in case it helps:

```
import bottle
from bottle import route, static_file

@route('/files/<filename>')
def serve_somefile(filename):
    return static_file(filename, root= '/Users/ron/Documents/so/25043651')

bottle.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```